# Delphi Tstringlist, get strings as a quoted, comma delimited string?

Tags: delphi, csv, tstringlist

I have a Tstringlist containing a list of keys used in a database table.
I'd like a simple way to generate one string containing all the keys, with each separated by a comma and enclosed in single quotes.
This is so that it can be used in a SQL 'IN' statement 
eg *WHERE FieldX IN ('One','Two','Three')*.

I've tried using quotechar but it is ignored when *reading* the commatext.
eg the following code

```
procedure junk;
var
  SL : Tstringlist;
  s : string;
begin
 SL := Tstringlist.Create;
 SL.Delimiter :=','; //comma delimiter
 SL.QuoteChar := ''''; //single quote around strings
 SL.Add('One');
 SL.Add('Two');
 SL.Add('Three');
 try
   s :=  SL.commatext;
   showmessage(s);
 finally
   SL.Free;
 end; //finally
end; //junk
```

shows the message  One,Two,Three  - without any quotes.

I know I can do it the long way round, as in

```
procedure junk;
var
  SL : Tstringlist;
  s : string;
  i : integer;
begin
 SL := Tstringlist.Create;
 SL.Delimiter :=','; //comma delimiter
 SL.Add('One');
 SL.Add('Two');
 SL.Add('Three');
 try
 s := '';
 for I := 0 to SL.Count - 1 do
    begin
    s := s +  ',' + '''' + SL[i] + '''';
    end;
 delete(s,1,1);
 showmessage(s);
 finally
   SL.Free;
 end;//finally
end;
```

but is there a simpler way using properties of the Tstringlist itself?

Comment: Your attempts to do this are insufficient because you don't escape quote characters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using D2006 or later, you can use a CLASS HELPER:

```
USES Classes,StrUtils;

TYPE
  TStringListHelper = CLASS HELPER FOR TStrings
                        FUNCTION ToSQL : STRING;
                      END;

FUNCTION TStringListHelper.ToSQL : STRING;
  VAR
    S : STRING;

  FUNCTION QuotedStr(CONST S : STRING) : STRING;
    BEGIN
      Result:=''''+ReplaceStr(S,'''','''''')+''''
    END;

  BEGIN
    Result:='';
    FOR S IN Self DO BEGIN
      IF Result='' THEN Result:='(' ELSE Result:=Result+',';
      Result:=Result+QuotedStr(S)
    END;
    IF Result<>'' THEN Result:=Result+')'
  END;
```

This code:

```
SL:=TStringList.Create;
SL.Add('One');
SL.Add('Two');
SL.Add('Number Three');
SL.Add('It''s number 4');
WRITELN('SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE FIELD IN '+SL.ToSQL);
```

will then output:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE FIELD IN ('One','Two','Number Three','It''s number 4')
```

Comment: Helpful answer. I have already written a whole unit's worth of helper functions exactly as you suggest that do things like ToSQL.text,  ToSQL.date  etc as well as the opposite, eg FromDB.date, FromSQL.time etc to make it easy to generate sql using delphi variables. In essence you are suggesting that it just put my 'long way' code above in a packaged form inside that unit. Good idea for neatness but does not really answer my actual question re whether Tstringlist can do it by itself

Comment: It can't - but by using a CLASS HELPER you can make it look like it can :-)

Comment: I think I shall accept your answer, partly because you have in fact  answered the question - albeit by saying it can't be done <grin> and partly because doing as you suggest and putting my 'long way' code inside another helper function does indeed make it look like it is Tstringlist that is doing the work.

Answer (score 4):

Use `sl.DelimitedText` instead of `sl.CommaText` to make it follow your settings. `CommaText` will temporarily change the `Delimiter` and `QuoteChar` to some hardcoded values.

Comment: I had already tried that, it makes no difference, it still comes out as One,Two,Three  with no single quotes arount the values.

Comment: @user3209752: It could be because there's no need to quote the strings, as there are no spaces or commas in them. Try with values that contain commas and/or spaces...

Comment: But I need them quoted in the final comma delimited string otherwise the SQL using that string will interpret them as column names instead of string literals. ie FieldX IN (one,two,three) is very different to FieldX IN ('One','Two','Three')

Comment: The docs actually supports you: `When retrieving DelimitedText, the resulting value delimits individual strings in two ways: each string is surrounded (before and after) by the quotation marks character specified by the QuoteChar property. In addition, individual strings are separated by the character specified by the Delimiter property.`. It just doesn't do what is stated in the first part (at least not for single word strings)

Answer (score 0):

CommaText (and apparently also DelimitedText) can not be relied on to add the quotes, because they treat single word and multi word strings differently.

> When retrieving CommaText, any string in the list that include spaces,
>   commas or quotes will be contained in double quotes, and any double
>   quotes in a string will be repeated.

There doesn't seem to be any combination with the TStringList alone, so I suggest you add the strings using `QuotedStr`.
Following settings work as you wish, regardless of, whether strings are single words or multi words:

```
 SL := Tstringlist.Create;
 SL.Delimiter :=','; //comma delimiter
 SL.StrictDelimiter := True;
// SL.QuoteChar := ''''; //single quote around strings
// SL.Add('One');
// SL.Add('Two words');
// SL.Add('Three');
 SL.Add(QuotedStr('One'));
 SL.Add(QuotedStr('Two words'));
 SL.Add(QuotedStr('Three'));
 s := SL.CommaText; // or SL.DelimitedText;
 showmessage(s);
```

Output is:

> 'One','Two words','Three'

Comment: [`StrictDelimiter`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.Classes.TStrings.StrictDelimiter) does not do what you may wonder

Comment: @fantaghirocco Ohh? What might that be?

Comment: was one of my tests: have you tried your code? it does not print the quotes as expected. It seems there's not an easy way...

Comment: @fantaghirocco As you see on the last line. But rereading, my first statement about CommaText did not come through as intended. Thanks

Comment: in my last comment I did not notice the use of `QuotedStr`: obviously it prints what expected. My apologies O:-)

Comment: But putting the quotes into the string list in the first place is not much different to my 'long way' when I put the quotes in afterwards. I still can't get a stringlist to put them in for me. I did try StrictDelimiter = true but, as you found out, it makes no difference on OUTPUT, only when loading the stringlist in the first place. In my case the actual stringlist gets loaded via other programming code, not the simplistic way I showed in my example, so I can't put the quotes in at source

Comment: @user3209752 The end result compared with your 'long way' is essentially the same, but nicer to code. There seems to be a bug with  TStringList, I 'm investigating.

Answer (score 0):

The `TStrings.DelimitedText` methods quote only the strings when needed: when there's something link `O'ne` this will print as `'O''ne'` - i.e. it double the quotes.

You can achieve what you want setting a convenience delimiter and the `QuoteChar` property to the `#0` value and then replacing the delimiters with the quotes.

```
procedure junk;
var
  sl : Tstringlist;
  s: string;
begin
  sl := Tstringlist.Create;
  try
    sl.Delimiter := '|';
    sl.QuoteChar := #0;//no quote
    sl.Add('On''e');
    sl.Add('Two');
    sl.Add('Three');

    //escape the single quotes
    s := StringReplace(sl.DelimitedText, '''', '''''', [rfReplaceAll]);

    //replace the delimiters and quote the text
    s := '''' +  StringReplace(s, sl.Delimiter, ''',''', [rfReplaceAll]) + '''';

    WriteLn(s);

  finally
    sl.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: That is even more complicated than my 'long way' ! You are telling the string list what to expect by way of delimiters in its input string, which I cannot do as the input is generated elsewhere without delimiters, plus you are explicitly putting quotes around each string which, for the same reason I cannot do. I cannot change what the stringlist contains in the first place. It looks like a variation of my 'long way' is going to be the only way

Comment: the strings of the `sl` object never change. You can assign the `Delimiter` and `QuoteChar` even after the list is filled with the values. This influence only the `DelimitedText` output

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved a similar issue with something like that :

```
  s := ''' + StringReplace(sl.CommaText, ',', ''',''', [rfReplaceAll]) + '''
```

Comment: Will fail if one of the entries in the string list contains a comma... Or if one of the entries contain a single quote...